# Avoid report to verified/code-review flag for a specific Jenkins Job

Tags: jenkins, gerrit-trigger

I'm using Jenkins with gerrit trigger.

We have a global gerrit trigger configuration that says that if a build is marked as NOT_BUILT the plugin should overwrite verified and code-review flag on gerrit with 0.

I can't change the default configuration of the plugin but for a certain job I need to avoid that overwrite in case the build is in NOT_BUILT status.

Is there an easy way to achieve that without installing additional plugins?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suppose you don't want to "silence" the job (use the "Silent Mode" option), right?

You could try to use the "Skip Vote" option:

[image]

But I'm really not sure if it will work.

Comment: Can you configure that at job level? I did not find this option in the configure job

Comment: Yes, click on the "Advanced..." button at the "Gerrit Trigger" section.